# searching and filtering not working react redux-thun

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am currently working on a task  in react and  redux. My question is this when the dom is loaded the view is updated with the content but as soon as a try to type on the input field everything disappears. Another thing i noticed is that i took same project to code sandbox but its not working. Please someone should assist me have cracked my head on this to no avail.my code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/long-glade-b8wr8?file=/src/component/Navbar.js&resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800